# How to expand label in UITableViewCell once tapping on the cell?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uilabel

In my description label, I want only the first 3 lines to be displayed in the label and when I tap on the cell, the label should expand and show the remaining lines.

[image]

Comment: once you use the auto layout to constraint the cell, then you just reload the row of the cell clicked, and change the label's  `numberOfLine`, it will work.

Comment: in auto layout , the system will do that for you, look this tutorial     http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18746929/using-auto-layout-in-uitableview-for-dynamic-cell-layouts-variable-row-heights/18746930#18746930